# Work done by forces on an elastic body

Tags: elasticity

What is the general formula for the work done by external forces on an elastic body? I assume it should be a formula involving the deformation gradient, the forces and an integral... I can't seem to find a concise and simple formula. I don't want to find a special case formula for a specific geometry.. If I have the general formula I'll do the integrations myself :)

Comment: It's equal to the change in the elastic energy function, integrated over the volume of the body.